# Angular directive isolate scope to parent binding undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, restangular

I'm using (the awesome) Restangular and i'm running into something that forces me to use `scope.$parent` (not awesome), and i don't want to use that. It seems even though my controller is the parent scope to my directive's scope, the `=` isolated scope binding is evaluated before my parent controller is executed.

With the following HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="myController">
    <div x-my-directive x-some-value="parentValue"></div>
</div>
```

And the following directive:

```
myApp.directive("myDirective", function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, elem) {
            console.log(scope.someValue); // Logs 'undefined' :(
        },
        scope: {
            someValue: "="
        }
    }
});
```

And the following controller:

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, allMyValues) {
    allMyValues.getList().then(function(parentValue){
        $scope.parentValue = parentValue;
    });
}
```

As shown in my directives `link` function, evaluating a scope property that should have been bound to my parent's scope property returns `undefined`. However when i change my directives `link` function to the following:

```
    myApp.directive("myDirective", function () {
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function (scope, elem) {
               setTimeout(function() {
                  console.log(scope.someValue); // Logs '{1: number_1, 2: number_2}'
                }, 2000);
            },
            scope: {
                someValue: "="
            }
        }
    });
```

How do i go about resolving this??

Thanks

Comment: seems to working fine for me please see here http://jsbin.com/komikitado/1/edit how do you set values in  $scope.parentValue?

Comment: @sylwester Sorry i just modified the question: i'm using Restangular in my controller (stupid to not add that in the first place, i know)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

that should helps:

```
myApp.controller("myController", function($scope, allMyValues) {
//add this line
$scope.parentValue={};

    allMyValues.getList().then(function(parentValue){
        $scope.parentValue = parentValue;
    });
}
```

$scope.parentValue not exist until your request is resolved so add line like below to your code
sample demo http://jsbin.com/komikitado/1/edit

Comment: This resolved my issue, only thing left to do was a `$scope.$apply()`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are waiting for a promise to resolve before assigning the value to the scope.

There are a few ways you might handle this.

One way is to try moving the Restangular call to a resolve function for the view which holds the controller.  Then you get access to the resolved data directly as an injection in your controllers

Another way might be to just assign the promise directly to the scope and then in the linking function wait for a resolution.

```
scope.someValue.then(function(value) { console.log(value); });
```

Comment: Even though it's working now, your solution seems more professional. I'll look into it, thanks!